# Ordering a list of objects by a particular attribute in Java after intersection

Tags: java, java-8

I think I'm over-complicating what I'm trying to do, but what I want is my list of objects to be ordered based on the input of the user. Here is some background context.

I have a `Schema` object, which has many `Field`(s). The user specifies the order in which these values get serialized (if they exist) like so:

`id, dateTime, payload` where those values *should* exist on the schema. If not, I filter them out. I perform an intersection on what the user wants and what the schema has like so:

```
  private List<Field> performIntersection(List<String> subsetFields, List<Field> allFields) {
    return allFields.stream()
        .distinct()
        .filter(field -> subsetFields.contains(field.name()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

This intersection *contains* exactly what I want, but I want to preserve the order that they specify. For example, if they specify `id, dateTime, payload` I want the list to be ordered like that. Is there a small little modification I can make to do that? The string value correlates to the method I call on `Field::name`

This works for me but ugly:

```
  private List<Field> performIntersection(List<String> subsetFields, List<Field> allFields) {
    AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger();
    return allFields.stream()
        .filter(field -> {
          if (subsetFields.get(idx.get()).equals(field.name())) {
            idx.getAndIncrement();
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Comment: Is `Field` a class in your project?

Comment: No. Field is an Avro field from Apache

Comment: I know contains is messing with it here, since it'll scan the list of N items, but it's killing the order. I know a queue could work, but too messy if I start polling

Comment: @Bohemian I added working code that is too ugly for me to want to use, but gets across what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) together with a comparator which looks at the index of the item in the list

```
return allFields.stream()
    .distinct()
    .filter(field -> subsetFields.contains(field.name()))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(field -> subsetFields.indexOf(field.name())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Ryan Sure, no problem

Answer (score 1):

If you care for efficiency, especially when the lists could be large, you should avoid repeated linear searches like `contains` and `indexOf`, which would give the operation O(n×m) time complexity. Using a temporary map with efficient lookup will provide O(n+m) time complexity:

```
private List<Field> performIntersection(List<String> subsetFields, List<Field> allFields){
  Map<String, Field> all = allFields.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::name, Function.identity(), (a,b)->a));
  return subsetFields.stream()
      .map(all::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that using `(a,b)->a` as merge function for `toMap` means “keep the previous” in case of duplicate keys, which has the same effect as the `distinct()` in your code (assuming that uniqueness for your fields is determined by their names).

Further, the result does already have the desired order without the need for sorting, as it stems from streaming over `subsetFields`. I use `filter(Objects::nonNull)` to eliminate names of `subsetFields` not present in `allFields`, as your code would do. If names are supposed to always map to an existing `Field`, you can remove this filter step.